# Is there a way to detect web server in case it's not present in HEADER?

Tags: webserver, http, detection

I'm trying to detect what web server a particular website uses. For instance whether it's nginX, Apache, Tomcat and so on.

I usually use `Live HTTP Headers` Firefox add-on. The problem is that sites sometimes hide their back-end. Isn't there a way to detect web servers when they're not present in HEADER?

**EDIT 1:**
A sample output from a website that didn't match to any of the `@Question Overflow`'s answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 10:43:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: VideoHosting Framework/1.0.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-cache="Set-Cookie", private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Videohost/1.0.1
```

**I even** tried to use `httprint` on linux but it gives `ICMP request timeout` on every website I tested.

**EDIT 2:**
The above HEADER is very similar to a website that I'm sure it uses nginX.
If we remove those parts that are not present (`Connection`, `Pragma` and so on) in the above HEADER, it gets so similar to nginX. I suppose `Server` is at the end of the `response` because they have customized it themeselves. And because of that nginX appended it to the end of the `Response` packet.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 12:51:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

OWASP should update its list with this one as well for nginX. ;-)

Comment: Use option [`-P0`](http://net-square.com/images/httprint/httprint_cli_usage.txt) to turn off the ICMP probe. ICMP is disabled on some servers, e.g. amazon aws.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If a website does not use a custom built server to modify the HTTP headers, you can try by examining the **order of arrangement** in the HTTP response fields. From [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fingerprint_Web_Server_%28OTG-INFO-002%29):

Apache 1.3.23 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: ...
Server: ...
Last-Modified: ...
ETag: ...
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Content-Length: ...
Connection: ...
Content-Type: text/HTML
```

Microsoft IIS 5.0 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: ...
Expires: ...
Date: ...
Content-Type: text/HTML 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
Last-Modified: ...
ETag: ...
Content-Length: ...
```

Netscape Enterprise 4.1 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: ...
Date: ...
Content-type: text/HTML 
Last-modified: ...
Content-length: ...
Accept-ranges: bytes 
Connection: ...
```

SunONE 6.1 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ...
Date: ...
Content-length: ...
Content-type: text/html
Date: ...
Last-Modified: ...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: ...
```

For further confirmation, you can send a **malformed request**, such as `GET / HTTP/3.0`, to elicit a non-standard response. Example:

Apache 1.3.23 and SunONE 6.1 servers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Microsoft IIS 5.0 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Netscape Enterprise 4.1 server:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

As the above information is pretty outdated, you may want to install a pentesting tool like [httprint](http://www.net-square.com/httprint.html) for **automated web server fingerprinting**.

Web servers can obfuscate their signature or masquerade themselves as another server. Take the information with a pinch of salt, if you must.

Comment: Thanks. It's weired that OWASP has not listed NginX as one the web servers?! `httprint` gives `ICMP timeout`  and didn't work for any site.

Comment: Your `OWASP` approach solved the problem. +1

Comment: @AlirezaHos, OWASP is just showing some basic examples, hence NginX is not shown. Are the servers you are testing ICMP-enabled?

Answer (score 7):

You can try looking if you can get the server to display a native error page. Error pages can be customized by a web developer, but when they aren't, they often reveal a lot of information about the web server.

For example, this is the *404 Not Found* error page of Apache 2.2.4 running on Unix:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /server-status was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.4 (Unix) mod_antiloris/0.4 Server at example.com Port 3128</address>
</body></html>
```

And this is the *400 Bad Request* error page (obtained by sending an HTTP request consisting of only `GET / HTTP/1.1` using telnet) sent by the same server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.4 (Unix) mod_antiloris/0.4 Server at 203.0.113.113 Port 3128</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The easiest way is trying to access to the `.htaccess` file. In most servers, it will trigger the error `300`. Most famous websites have that part covered up.

Comment: Unfortunately they've customized their page, but thanks for the input. Cheers ;-))))

Answer (score -3):

Why not just use [nmap](http://nmap.org) to detect what web server software is being used?

Comment: The tools is not important all of them gave the same header result. I need a solution similar to @Question Overflow to detect the web server.